# JsDoc: Defining param type to be a type from an external module

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, jsdoc

This seems like it should have an obvious answer but I can't find it.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
/**
* @param {Mongoose.Model} fooModel
*/
function ExecuteAQueryUsingModel(fooModel) {
```

I am essentially trying to define the parameter to be a `Mongoose.Model`, a variable constructed with the mongoose model constructor. I don't know how to set the jsdoc types to be types defined externally like this.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
/**
* @param {mongoose.Model} fooModel
*/
function ExecuteAQueryUsingModel(fooModel) {
```

Types are available from the `mongoose` variable you've already created above. And for whenever you don't need to `require(` a JS variable you could do so in the type definition:

```js
/**
* @param {require('mongoose').Model} fooModel
*/
function ExecuteAQueryUsingModel(fooModel) {
```

Answer (score -1):

I may be on thin ice here, since I'm just a hobbyist, and I'm only using JSDoc to get IntelliSense in Visual Studio Code.
This JSDoc solved my problem:

```
/** @param {import("express").Response} expressResponse */
function send(expressResponse) {
    expressResponse.send('OK');
}
```

I was not able to find the syntax in http://usejsdoc.org/tags-param.html so this could be specific to typescript.
Here's where I found the idea: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-checking-javascript-files.html

Hope this gives some help although it may not be completely correct.